# Java multithreading doesn't use the threads at 100%

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

I have this program that has to run 10k times a specific method, which is fairly heavy, every time with different input.

I tried both to thread it naturally (one thread per input) and tried to thread it with `nr_threads= Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` threads, or 2-3 times that amount (the method has different complexity based on the input, so I found out that if I deploy exactly nr_threads threads, then one usually is still alive when all the other threads are dead.

When I run it locally on my computer (4 physical cores, 8 considering the virtual ones) it runs at 100%, but every time I try to run it on a server (amazon instances, if that matters), where I have 36 or 72 cores, the average load per thread is between 15 and 25%.

I use a Callable class for the multithreading, and from that one I call only static methods. I also update a matrix, but I'm sure that no two threads try to access the same cell, so it shouldn't be a concurrency issue. RAM usage is also fairly safe ( 40GB out of 60 ), so I would exclude intense GC activity. But I have no idea how to test GC activity.

Does anyone know why it's using only 25% of each thread?

Also, I get that 10k threads might be a bit overwhelming for the computer to handle, but I found no info about it. Is there a best practice when it comes down to the number of threads deployed?

[This is another section of the program, that deploys 10000 threads all of them heavily loaded. It takes 15 minutes to complete.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn87a.png)

[This is the code I am referring to, it deploys 5 times the available processors (so 180 in total). It takes around 10 minutes to complete. Nothing changes if I run 10000 threads instead.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWGZN.png)

Comment: Try to ask only one question at a time, you have 2 currently. Besides that: Could you provide a bit more input? How long are your tasks running? How many cores(physical/virtual) do you have available on your server? Does this happen with every application or just yours? How about a dummy idle task that just hugs resources? How are you monitoring CPU Utilization? Are you calculating only calculating idle time vs. active time or maybe measuring idle time + waiting time vs. active time? There is a lot of potential reasons why your problem occurs and I would assume it's not Amazon's fault.

Comment: (I would even go so far as to say there is potential that there is no problem and it's just a perceived problem from the outside thanks to wrong measurement of utilization in combination with unoptimized code)

Comment: I asked them together because I thought there was a common answer.
I have 36, 72 and 144 threads if I remember correctly. No matter how many the instance has, the CPU load is still below 25% per thread. That I measure with htop, when logging in in the instances. That part of the application runs for 10 minutes ( after multithreading, no matter which one I use) I also have another part of the same application that deployes exactly 10k threads, but they're super heavily loaded and kind of equally loaded, in that part I use 100% of the threads all the time (that part takes 15 minutes).

Comment: what is "load per thread"? How do you measure it? I only know load per processor.

Comment: Okay, my bad. With "Per thread" I meant per virtual core. The instance I'm using now has 18 physical cores, 36 with hyper threading. Htop shows all of them and shows the load per each core.

Comment: Could you share your htop output?

Comment: First phase, the one that takes 15 minutes: http://tinypic.com/r/r23qqo/9.

Second phase, the one I'm not happy about ( and it takes 10 minutes): http://tinypic.com/r/x0vj3p/9 The load average is considerably lower, even though the number of threads deployed is much lower. Could it be that it's allocating space for arrays?

Comment: Could you please add the images to your question and use the stack overflow image site to upload them? Thank you.

Comment: Done! Thanks, I was unsure on how to post pictures in the comments otherwise. @Ben